# Exim4 on server. Sending to it from another smtp. Sender verify failed

Tags: email, exim, exim4

I have Exim on server with test@domain.com email.
And now i'm sending email to test@domain.com from test2@domain.com but using provider SMTP and i'm getting following error:

```
Failed: test2@domain.com → test@domain.com 'Microsoft Office Outlook Test Message' Server response: 
550 550 Verification failed for <bounce+2db7fb.5fc31-info=test@domain.com> Unrouteable address Sender verify failed
```

How can i put my SMTP (sender) to white list?

Answer (score 0):

Have you correctly setup your domain MX record your server ? I think there is an issues with the mx record of your domain.

Comment: I can receive email from any other emails such as Gmail Yahoo and other, the problem is to send email within my domain but using ISP smtp.